# How call many events function in javascript and call VB behind code sequentially by press asp.net button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I request from the user fill some text box in(asp.net) about his info,then he/she press 
button  for show his result, I make some javascript code to validate user input on evrey textbox.
(all what I want >>> do not to show the result before verifying user data.)
I make asp.net botton and call javascript event fun by OnClientClick and it is work .
I request from the user fill some text box in(asp.net) about his info,then he/she press 
button  for show his result, I make some javascript code to validate user input on evrey textbox.
(all what I want >>> do not to show the result before verifying user data.)
I make asp.net botton and call javascript event fun by OnClientClick and it is work .

but How I can call  VB behind fun code execute after javascript event fun and in the same button??
Please I realy need any one help me .
Thanks

but How I can call  VB behind fun code execute after javascript event fun and in the same button??
Please I realy need any one help me .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is change your button to a standard HTML button that invokes a javascript and then set a style of `display:none` to your ASP.NET button.

You can perform your client side validation from the javascript executed by the HTML button and if validation passes then programmatically invoke the click event on the ASP.NET button.

This will ensure that your client validation will get executed first.

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clientValidations() {
    // If validation passes then submit
    if (checkText1() & checkText2() & getIndex() & checkText3()) {
      var aspButton = //Find ASP Button by clientID
      aspButton.click();
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Define class 'hidden' as display:none -->
<input type="button" onclick="clientValidations();" value="Submit" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" class="hidden" />
```

Comment: realy I thank to u for answer me ,but can you clear more ,you mean make two buttons?? one asp.net button and standerd HTML button?

Comment: Sorry,I make one button asp.net for VB code behind diplay:non and also make anthor button for javascript validation???but Iwanna user press one button now tow !!if user press one button anther button hidden is work?? please could u explain more this my code :  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"     OnClientClick="return checkText1() & 

checkText2() & getIndex() & checkText3() "    UseSubmitBehavior="false"   />

Comment: I added a code example to my answer above.  This demonstrates the approach.

Comment: I do the same code example which added , every thinge is work just the VB behind code still not .I think propleme in clientID ,please can u help me how can write the clientID of asp.net button .casue I try many ways to make it but still doesn't work this ways like:var aspButton =document.getElementById('<% Button3.clientID %>').value;   
       in clientValidations() javascript fun. With sincere thanks and appreciation

Comment: You don't need the .value on that line.  Just get the variable for the button itself like this: var aspButton = document.getElementById('<% Button3.clientID %>');